# Adding two arraylists to a custom layout?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFOO8.png)
I have two `arraylists` and I have created a custom layout in my res folder with two `TextViews` side by side. I want to be able to populate this `customlayout` with the two `arraylists` so that the first item in the first list will be displayed beside the first item in the second list. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The Two Arraylists with the Listview:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.getKey();
                allStudentsList.add(name);
                attendancePercentage.add("74%");
            }
            final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.studentList);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.percentage_layout, R.id.statsResult, allStudentsList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The XML File for the custom Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statsResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="TextView" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: will the arrays have the same number of rows? will the rows have the same size? try to put a wireframe of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes they will have the same amount of rows, so the first arraylist is going to be a class list. The second list will be the attendance record for that particular student. In the above code, I have just hardcoded that every student will have 74% beside them

Comment: Added an Image of what I would like to look like

Comment: Please use custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide both list to yourAdapter

using constructor or setterMethod

```
 public YourAdapter(List<Name> nameList,List<Percent> nameList, Context context) {
    this.nameList = nameList;
    this.nameList = nameList;
    this.context = context;
}
```

then 
modify your onBindMethod

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(YourHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvName.setText(listName.getName());
    holder.tvPercent.setText(listPercent.getPercent());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class like this:

```
public class Student {

String name;
String percentage;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPercentage() {
    return percentage;
}

public void setPercentage(String percentage) {
    this.percentage = percentage;
}
```

}

and call adapter like:

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.percentage_layout,ListallStudentsList);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);